# Partitial Differential equation systems: Inexact equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> How to solve the given system for $q_1$,$q_2$,$q_3$?:
> $$q_2[-q_1\gamma_{14}+(1-q_2)\gamma_{24}-q_3\gamma_{34}]dq_1-q_1[(1-q_1)\gamma_{14}-q_2\gamma_{24}-q_3\gamma_{34}]dq_2=0$$
> $$q_3[-q_1\gamma_{14}-q_2\gamma_{24}+(1-q_3)\gamma_{34}]dq_2-q_2[-q_1\gamma_{14}+(1-q_2)\gamma_{24}-q_3\gamma_{34}]dq_3=0$$
> $$q_1[(1-q_1)\gamma_{14}-q_2\gamma_{24}-q_3\gamma_{34}]dq_3-q_3[-q_1\gamma_{14}-q_2\gamma_{24}+(1-q_3)\gamma_{34}]dq_1=0$$

when evey $\gamma_{ij}$ is known parameter